# eventlistener on nested classnames

Tags: javascript, onclick, nested, getelementsbyclassname

I want to toggle the class "collapsed" on every element with the class "category" when it's clicked. The Problem is, that the "category" elements are nested in each other and the child elements also toggle the class on their parents.

An Example

HTML structure:

```
<div class="category">
    <div class="category">
        <div class="category"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="category">
    <div class="category"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var categories = document.getElementsByClassName("category");
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    categories[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.classList.toggle("collapsed");
    });
}
```

When I click the nested element, the "this" selector will also select the parent elements with the class "category".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the event bubbles out and triggers on all the container elements with the class. You should call `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent this.

```
var categories = document.getElementsByClassName("category");
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    categories[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        this.classList.toggle("collapsed");
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you then explain why it won't work in this case, to prevent the anchor from fire and navigate: http://jsfiddle.net/4kdg7ptx/2/

Comment: Is it because it only stops propagate the `click` event, which the anchor actually doesn't have one set up, assuming the `href` event is not the same, and if so, how to stop the navigation from fire?

Comment: You also need `e.preventDefault()` to override the default action of clicking on the link. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/4kdg7ptx/7/

Comment: Ok, thanks, using that elsewhere though hoped for a solution w/o it.